# Need a specific regex to get the data from this specific link structure

Tags: php, regex

I need to get the url or the number (this number is just for example but all the numbers have 7 digits) using regex? It is mandatory not to match all the `<a>` available in the HTML file, but with this exact structure.

```
<a href="./view/3049532/">
```

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: So what have you tried? You could try to match 7 digits, which will be found in any regex tutorial, or you could match everything between the `"` marks...

Comment: You may be able to modify this regex to fit your language: <a href="./view/(\d{7})/">  ... The digits are captured in a group. And like darthbith said you should be able to find it in any regex tutorial.

Comment: And how you get this anchor? if you're using a dom parser, you can easily retrieve the `href` attribute from where you extract properly the digits...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not hard even a little.

```
/<a\s+href="\.\/view\/(\d{7})\/">/
```

[See demo](http://regex101.com/r/nL7nV1)

```
<?php
$page_content = <<<THIS
<a href="./view/3049532/">
<a href="./view/398562/">
<a href="./view/3652872/">
<a href="./view/3785471/">
THIS;
    preg_match_all('/<a\s+href="\.\/view\/(\d{7})\/">/', $page_content, $matches);
    print_r($matches[1]);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 3049532
    [1] => 3652872
    [2] => 3785471
)
```

*and also according to others words just use regex if it's your last choice!*